# Biography on Georg Cantor

Tags: mathematics, mathematicians, biographical-details, reference-request, cantor

I am looking for biographical works about Georg Cantor's life.

All I have found right now are short encyclopedia-style articles that skim the important points of his life or works mainly focused on his mathematical contributions; ideally I want something more thorough that has a greater emphasis on his life in general rather than just his mathematical contributions. I came across this book, 'Georg Cantor: Leben, Werk und Wirkung' by Herbert Meschkowski, that seems to be what I'm looking for, but unfortunately I haven't found a copy yet.

I would prefer books, but any other references (papers, websites, etc.) that you'd think would be interesting or useful are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments on Math Stack Exchange, Dauben's book is highly regarded.  For reference, here's a link to the [Dauben book review](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1980-02-01/S0273-0979-1980-14725-4/S0273-0979-1980-14725-4.pdf) published in the Bulletin of the AMS.

Comment: @Eduardo M. - Dauben's book is the standard "intellectual biography". For German readers, see also: Walter Purkert & Hans Joachim Ilgauds, [Georg Cantor: 1845–1918](https://books.google.it/books?id=vQWbBgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) (1985).